# My build method is no longer working in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

After spending days working on the user profile section of my website I've now found that build_profile does not work.

I don't know what is wrong,it doesn't make sense as it was working perfectly fine the other day. Now it doesn't create a row in the profiles table every time a new user is created.

Here is my users controller create action code:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])   
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save 
        @user.build_profile.save #same as Profile.new(:user_id => @user.id)
        login @user
        UserMailer.join_confirmation(@user).deliver
        format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{root_path}'" } 
     #   flash[:notice] = "Welcome!"
      else

        format.js   { render :form_errors }
      end
    end
  end
```

Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  # Setter and getter methods
  attr_accessor :password # virtual password attribute


  # A list of white list of attributes accessible by users in forms
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user



 #  attr_accessor   :password
   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :motd, :birthday, 
   :marital_status, :sexual_preference, :location, :country, :ethnicity, 
    :about_me, :height, :eye_colour, :body_type, :likes, :dislikes, :drugs,
    :alcohol, :cigarettes, :bad_habits, :food, :music, :television, :book,
    :animal, :place, :possession, :sport
```

Bang method error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `build_profile' for #<UsersController:0x00000101d63510>):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

It's really annoying as i've been working hard on this and out of the blue it no longer works.

I would really appreciate some help with this
Kind regards

**Update**

rspec error:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController JOIN 'create' success should create a user
     Failure/Error: post :create, :user => @user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `ethnicity' for #<Profile:0x0000010367cab0>
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `block in create'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:96:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.75 seconds
47 examples, 1 failure, 1 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:94 # UsersController JOIN 'create' success should create a user
```

Strange! I've done checks and that attribute exists in my db and on the attr_accessible list so I'm quite baffled.

I dropped and re-migrated and still no luck.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you should write tests for your website. After you implemented some code, your tests would have failed, and you could have seen right away what did it. Try looking up the built in test suites, as well as cucumber, which is a great acceptance test gem in my opinion.

Comment: I have rspec installed but got lazy and stopped using it. I really do understand the importance of tests now. First lesson learned. Thought since it's not a large site I was building I could get away with minimal tests.

Comment: I loaded up rspec because I had some tests written for my users_controller and it's telling me I have an undefined method "ethnicity" for profile. I've check the DB and it's there, and I've also checked my attr_accessible list

Comment: Where is the `build_profile` method that `@user.build_profile` is trying to use?  I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
:before_create :build_profile
```

to the users model did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *profile_attributes* to your attr_accessible call inside the parent model, in this case User. Please see docs: api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html